# Changing the final value in loop after one iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iteration

> Design the source code to print the Knight sequence of a given number n.
> Knight Sequence of a number starts with itself, the remaining terms of the sequence are
> the sum of proper divisors of the immediate previous term.
>
> Examples:
>  The knight sequence for 10 is 10, 8, 7, 1, 0.
> (Sum of proper divisors of 10 is 5 + 2 + 1 = 8.
> Sum of proper divisors of 8 is 4 + 2 + 1 = 7.
> The Sum of proper divisors of 7 is 1.
> The Sum of proper divisors of 1 is 0.)
> Note that there is no proper divisor of 1.
>  The knight sequence for 6 is 6 (an infinite sequence of 6s).
> When the knight sequence is repeating, print the repeating number and stop.

I am trying to solve this question and wrote this code:

```
n = int(input('Enter the value: '))
l = [n]
s = 0

for i in range(1, n):
    if n % i == 0:
        s += i
l.append(s)

print(set(l))
```

and this gives the output as:

```
Enter the value: 10
{8, 10}
```

The issue is that I am not able to figure out that how to continue this iteration to find the rest of the sequence....pls help me out

Comment: Since this looks like homework, it would be wrong to give you the final solution right away, but here's a hint. I think this is meant to be treated recursively. Basically, `knight_val(10) = 10 + knight_val(sum(proper_divisors(10)))`.

Comment: You only append to the list once, not any other times